# What happens when water added to the ash?

Tags: water, flow

I am pouring some water (using falling by gravity) from my water bottle into the ash. The ash is not in heat conditions. Now the small particles from the ash come out proportional to the water flow.

Now my question is, why do the ash particles come out when pouring water?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't say what the ash is from, but fine ash is a [flocculate of very small particles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flocculation). As such, it has a very low density with air entrained within it.

When you add water the [capillary forces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Capillary_action) produced by the water collapse the structure and expel the air trapped within it. The emerging air carries particles of the ash, hence you see puffs of ash as you add the water.